# Why does this C code segfault?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void FillArray(int *array, int);
#define MAX 256

int main()
{
    int *array[MAX], size = 100;
    FillArray(*array, size);
    return 0;
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        temp = (rand()%101);
        *array = temp;
        printf ("array[%d]. %d\n", i, *array);
        array += i;
    }
    printf ("AJGIUEROGUSHFDJGJDFK/n");
}
```

I put the printf on the last line so that i could tell if it would reach that point, so far it hasn't.

Edit: I added code. I have to use pointer arithmetic instead of array indexes.

Comment: `int *array[MAX]` is an array of `MAX` **pointers to** `int`, from which you pass the 1st to the function. There are **no `int`s defined** where the latter points to.

Comment: `(P.S. it's in C)` -- You tagged the question `C`, mentioned `C code` in the title, and in the post itself.  Wow!

Comment: ah, that was my own stupidity

Comment: Turn on compiler compiler warnings. Read them. This would have been trivial to find.

Comment: Having SO do your homework now? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `array` in `main` is declared as an array of `int *` pointers. This array is not initialized, i.e. all elements contain garbage values.

Layer your `FillArray` call in `main`

```
FillArray(*array, size);
```

passes the value of `*array` to `FillArray` function. `*array` is the same as `array[0]` - it is an uninitialized garbage pointer that points nowhere.

Inside `FillArray` function you are attempting to access (and write) data through that uninitialized garbage pointer. Expectedly, the code crashes.

As is always the case with invalid code, there's no way to fix the error until you explain what you are trying to do.

I can only guess that all you needed is an array of `int` elements, not `int *` elements. I.e. your `array` in `main` was supposed to be declared as `int array[MAX]`. And `FillArray` should have been called as `FillArray(array, size)`. Also, inside the cycle it is supposed to be `array += 1` (or just `++array`), not your `array += i`, which does not make any sense.

Comment: I am trying to "create a function called FillArray() that accepts a pointer to an integer as the array name, an integer for its size. This function randomly fills the array with 
integers ranging from 0 to 100. Use pointer arithmetic".

Comment: @Fredamabob: See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If wanna fill the array passed to your function, then change

```
array = &temp;
```

to

```
*array = temp;
```

And also change

```
array += i;
```

to

```
array++;
```

EDIT: OP edited his question and want to fill an array of integers. You need to chage the declaration of your array

```
 int *array[MAX], size = 100;  // Declare an array of pointers
```

to

```
 int array[MAX], size = 100;   // Declates an array of ints
```

Comment: when i do that my program crashes instantly, instead of outputting all of the values of array and then crashing, which it normally does.

Comment: @Fredamabob The other (the now crashing) bug is in `array += i`.

Comment: The downvoter might like to explain: Assuming the function would be called correctly this answer it fine.

Comment: @alk; On SO some downvoter do not like to explain :).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop should just be:

```
int i, temp;
for (i = 0; i < size; i ++)
{
    temp = rand() % 101;
    array[i] = temp;
    printf ("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
}
```

This will do what you want. There's no need to re-assign `array` inside the function, although *you can*. It's easier to just use the indexing operator `[]`. Remember that

```
a[i]
```

is the same as

```
*(a + i)
```

regardless of the types involved (but generally `a` is a pointer type and `i` an unsigned integer) as long as the sum is a pointer of course.

There are errors in `main()`, too:

- The array should just be `int array[MAX];`.
- The call should just be `FillArray(array, size);`.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to include that i have to use pointer arithmetic

Comment: How is that going to help when `array` inside `FillArray` is a garbage pointer?

Answer (score 0):

probably your want.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void FillArray(int *array, int);
#define MAX 256

int main(){
    int array[MAX], size = 100;
    FillArray(array, size);
    return 0;
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *array = rand()%101;
        printf ("array[%d]. %d\n", i, *array);
        ++array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int *array[MAX]` is an array of `MAX` **pointers to `int`**, from which you pass the 1st to the function. There are **no `int`s defined** where the latter points to.

To fix this appliy the changes `void FillArray(int *array, int size)` provided by the other answers and then call it like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int array[MAX], size = 100;
  FillArray(array, size);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine except for your perception that *array = &array, which is wrong !!

Below points might help in understating pointers better:

1. *array = array[0]
2. array = &array[0]
3. *(array+i) = array[i]

Made changes to your code and it should work fine:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void FillArray(int *array, int);
#define MAX 256

int main()
{
    int *array, size = 100;
    array=(int *)calloc(MAX,sizeof(int));
    if(array !=NULL)
    {
        FillArray(array, size);    /* While calling send &array[0] but not array[0] */
    }
    return 0;
}

void FillArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        temp = (rand()%101);
        *(array+i) = temp;
        printf ("array[%d]. %d\n", i, *(array+i));
        /* array += i;             <-- not necessary */
    }
    printf ("AJGIUEROGUSHFDJGJDFK/n");
}
```